# How can I use performance data on Rinkeby to project performance data on the Ethereum Mainnet?

Tags: gas, testnets, testing, rinkeby

I'm testing a DApp on the Rinkeby testnet, and want to know how well it would perform on the mainnet if I deployed it there, specifically how much gas was consumed by the DApp. Is there any way for one to compare the statistics I gathered from Rinkeby to potential statistics on the mainnet?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gas costs of each of the opcodes are the same on the main and the test nets, so here nothing will change. The only difference will be the `gasprice` , which will often times be higher on the main net if you want transactions to go through faster. The [ETH gas station](https://ethgasstation.info/) provides you with real time data on gas prices.